# How do I disable "Restore Previous Session" in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox

For privacy I want to disable this feature in Firefox, so that when I open Firefox it loads my homepage, not restore the previous session tabs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following steps will be helpful to prevent firefox from restoring previous sessions.

1. In the Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.
2. The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise! to continue to the about:config page.
3. In the Search box at the top, type browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash.
4. In the resulting grid, double-click on browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash to set it to false.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Why go into `about:config` when this is something that is part of the Firefox Options window?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Still application will show the previous sessions in the case of crash if we set settings from the Firefox Options window.

Comment: Modifying the behavior "in case of crash" was not the question. Also, wouldn't your modification **only** stop it from restoring after crash? (I.e. it would still restore after being closed normally)

Comment: Agreed .. In that case we need to use both solutions. Apart form that not keeping the history will also prevent the firefox from showing previous sessions in any case (Crash / application exit)

Comment: Unless the question is modified, both solutions are not needed. The way the question is phrased right now, it's looking for a way to disable the behavior where tabs are restored every time you open Firefox. The requirement to remove this behavior does not necessarily mean that you want to remove this behavior upon a crash as well. Both answers could stand as they are and whoever comes here looking can take their pick.

Comment: Simply closing firefox appropriately will eliminate any attempt to restore a previous session since it won't exist.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Could you provide some details about that? I've just tried a few different ways of closing Firefox, and each time the session was restored the next time I opened it.

Comment: @ruakh Have you tried File->Quit? from the firefox menu?

Comment: @ElderGeek: I don't have a 'File' menu, but I've tried both 'Firefox Web Browser ▾ → Quit' and '[hamburger] → Quit', as well as Ctrl+Q (which is a shortcut for the latter).

Comment: @ruakh Interesting.  I suggest that you [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) after reviewing [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) referring to this question if you feel it provides context. I recommend that you include the output of `lsb_release -a
` and `firefox --version` in your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: This is the best answer because when you shut down the computer without closing Firefox (all the time) Firefox thinks it "crashed" and just restores the session regardless of the Options setting!  This make Firefox "messy" every time I open it. Just want a blank window.

The only thing this answer needs is an explanation of why it's necessary to change the setting this way.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Domarius. When terminating the system without closing Firefox, the session will be restored. But unfortunately the problem persists even after setting the above variable to false. However, the session is not restored when sending SIGKILL to the process. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/startup-home-page-download-settings

This article describes the settings that are available in the General panel of the Firefox Options window.

The General panel allows you to:

- Set what page(s) Firefox displays when you start your browser or click the Home icon
- Set what Firefox should do when downloading files

**Startup**

When Firefox starts: Controls what Firefox displays when you open it.

- **Show my home page** - Displays the home page, which is set below.
- Show a blank page - Displays a blank page, which is fastest to load.
- Show my windows and tabs from last time - Restores the pages you were visiting the last time you closed Firefox. For more information, see Restore previous session Configure when Firefox shows your most recent tabs and windows. ( <- Most likely your current setting )

Comment: When I close the Firefox with multiple tabs, I expect te FIrefox to reopen them later. But when I have there only one tab, I expect Firefox to NOT reopen in the next time. How should be Firefox configured to behave like this?

Comment: Why are you assuming that Firefox can be configured to behave like this?

Comment: That is the point, I have already opened a bug report for it with Mozilla.

Comment: Not really "the point" when you didn't mention it whatsoever in your initial comment

Comment: No, I reported it afterward...